# Replace array of 'Yes' and 'No' with binary values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as $array1 which contains a list of Yes and No values - what is the most elegant method to replace all Yes and No values with 1 and 0?

Language: PHP.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if your Yes and No values are normalized but you can do a case insensitive search with `str_ireplace()` using arrays.  If they are always consistent case then you can just use `str_replace()`.

```
$array1 = array('Yes','yes','NO','YES','no');
$array1_converted = str_ireplace(array('yes','no'), array(1,0), $array1);
print_r($array1_converted);

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 0
)
```

Comment: Correct. Yes/No are normalised and Yes/No can occur in any order. Yes, I'm learning and this helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `array_walk()`, like the following:

```
<?php
$arr = array('Yes', 'no', 'YeS');
array_walk($arr, function(&$item, $key){$item = strtolower($item)=='yes' ? 1 : 0; });
print_r($arr); // output array is [1, 0, 1]
?>
```

Comment: he said "elegant" ;-)

Comment: of course, i'm just kidding.. it's always interesting to see the different approaches to common problems.